# How to write this equation correctly

Tags: c++

Kinda new to c++ and can't figure out why the equation in this code doesn't work. I don't get any error but the result is nan(ind). I tried searching on the web but couldn't solve the problem.
I'm talking about the equation in the final part the one that's equal to "risultato".
The code is based on the rsi formula, you can find it here https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/rsi.asp and here in italian https://www.soldionline.it/guide/analisi-tecnica/rsi-misurare-gli-eccessi-del-mercato.
Ints and Floats are written in italian.

```
int main()
{

    int giorniCompletiAlRialzo, m;
    float rialzo[10];
    cout << endl << "N giorni completi al rialzo:";
    cin >> giorniCompletiAlRialzo;

    for (m = 0; m < giorniCompletiAlRialzo; m++)
    {
        cout << "dislivello " << m + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> rialzo[m];
    }

    float mediaGiorniCompletAlRialzo=0;
    for (m = 0; m < giorniCompletiAlRialzo; m++) {
        mediaGiorniCompletAlRialzo = mediaGiorniCompletAlRialzo + rialzo[m];
    }
    mediaGiorniCompletAlRialzo = (mediaGiorniCompletAlRialzo / m)*6;



    int giorniCompletiAlRibasso, n;
    float ribasso[10];
    cout << endl << "N giorni completi al ribasso:";
    cin >> giorniCompletiAlRibasso;
    for (n = 0; n < giorniCompletiAlRibasso; n++)
    {
        cout << "dislivello " << n + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> ribasso[n];
    }
    float mediaGiorniCompletAlRibasso=0;
    for (n = 0; n < giorniCompletiAlRibasso; n++) {
        mediaGiorniCompletAlRibasso = mediaGiorniCompletAlRibasso + rialzo[n];
    }
    mediaGiorniCompletAlRibasso = (mediaGiorniCompletAlRibasso / n)*6;


    float rialzoOre[60];
    int oreAlRialzo, o;
    cout << endl << "N periodi da 4 ore al rialzo:";
    cin >> oreAlRialzo;

    for (o = 0; o < oreAlRialzo; o++)
    {
        cout << "dislivello " << o + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> rialzoOre[o];
    }
    float mediaOreAlRialzo=0;
    for (o = 0; o < oreAlRialzo; o++) {
        mediaOreAlRialzo = mediaOreAlRialzo + rialzoOre[o];
    }
    mediaOreAlRialzo = mediaOreAlRialzo / o;


    float ribassoOre[60];
    int oreAlRibasso, p;
    cout << endl << "N periodi da 4 ore al ribasso:";
    cin >> oreAlRibasso;

    for (p = 0; p < oreAlRibasso; p++)
    {
        cout << "dislivello " << p + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> ribassoOre[p];
    }
    float mediaOreAlRibasso=0;
    for (p = 0; p <oreAlRibasso; p++) {
        mediaOreAlRibasso = mediaOreAlRibasso + ribassoOre[p];
    }
    mediaOreAlRibasso = mediaOreAlRibasso / p;

    

    float risultato;
    risultato = ((0-(30*giorniCompletiAlRialzo*mediaGiorniCompletAlRibasso) - (30 * giorniCompletiAlRialzo*mediaOreAlRibasso) - (5 * oreAlRialzo*mediaGiorniCompletAlRibasso) - (5 * oreAlRialzo*mediaOreAlRibasso)) / ((36*giorniCompletiAlRibasso)+(6*oreAlRibasso))) - mediaGiorniCompletAlRialzo - mediaOreAlRialzo;
    cout << endl << endl << "IL RISULTATO E': " << risultato<<endl;







    
    

        
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: welcome to programming! What have you tried to figure out? At some point your data becomes NaN, and simple "print before and after" debugging should very quickly let you figure out where.

Comment: It would be preferrable to keep reading input out of the [mcve], assuming it's not part of the issue. Furthermore using English language in the code would be preferrable, since this is the language everyone here should be able to understand.

Comment: Looks like an excellent example for using a debugger.  Use a debugger and post the results (in text) from your debugging session.

Comment: Also if the code expect user input to produce result, you should at least include some tested input, expected output, and actual output.